# using elasticsearch filter in logstash pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using the elasticsearch filter in my logstash pipeline. I correctly find the result using :

```
filter{
  if [class] == "DPAPIINTERNAL" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "10.1.10.16"
      index => "dp_audit-2017.02.16"
      query_template => "/home/vittorio/Documents/elastic-queries/matching-requestaw.json"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see, Im using "query_template" which is :

```
{
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
       "query": "class:DPAPI AND request.aw:%{[aw]}"
      }
    },
   "_source": ["end_point", "vittorio"]
 }
```

that tells elastichsearch to look up the log with that specific class that match "aw" with the DPAPIINTERNAL log.

Perfect! but now that i found the result, i want to add some field from it and attach them to my DPAPIINTERNAL log, for instance, i want to take "end_point" and add it in the new key "vittorio" inside my log.

This is not happening and I don't understand why.

here is the log that i'm looking at using the query:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "dp_audit-2017.02.16",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVpHoPHPuEPlW12Qu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "svc": "dp-1.1",
          "request": {
            "method": "POST|PATCH|DELETE",
            "aw": "prova",
            "end_point": "/bank/6311",
            "app_instance": "7D1-D233-87E1-913"
          },
          "path": "/home/vittorio/Documents/dpapi1.json",
          "@timestamp": "2017-02-16T15:53:33.214Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "host": "Vito",
          "event": "bank.add",
          "class": "DPAPI",
          "ts": "2017-01-16T19:20:30.125+01:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your need to specify the [`fields` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-fields) in your `elasticsearch` filter, like this:

```
elasticsearch {
  hosts => "10.1.10.16"
  index => "dp_audit-2017.02.16"
  query_template => "/home/vittorio/Documents/elastic-queries/matching-requestaw.json"
  fields => { "[request][end_point]" => "vittorio" }
}
```

Note that since `end_point` is a nested field, you need to modify the `_source` in your query template like this:

```
"_source": ["request.end_point"]
```

Comment: I've specified the fields in the query_template file :    "_source": ["end_point", "vittorio"]

Comment: In the template, you specify the fields you want to retrieve in your search, but in the `fields` parameter you actually assign those fields to your event.

Comment: I just did, I have null value in my new field.  :(

Comment: Oh I know why, `end_point` is a nested field actually. I've updated my answer

Comment: Are you certain that `"request.end_point"` is not null in the document that is retrieved?

Comment: that is a good question. I think if it finds the document using that query, it has all the fields.... so it must be not null. In the other index, im sure it is not null

Comment: also, im able to get all the fields but not the nested ones. For instance, I can't access anything inside "request"...

Comment: The query is on `class` and `request.aw`, that's no guarantee that `request.end_point` is not null

Comment: I posted the data I want to copy from... `end_point` is not null. Anyway, even if I just want `request.aw` the result is still the same : `null` value.

Comment: Solved! the problem is that in `_source` you don't specify the "new" fileld but only the once you want to take from the file. Then you specify the new field as `fields => { "request" => "vittorio" }`. In my case request is nested and it will be added as it is, with all the filed inside.

Comment: Glad you figured out. Indeed, I didn't know that `vittorio` was a field present in your source.

Comment: it helped a lot! but is not correct to specify the "destination" key in _source.

Comment: Well, my answer has exactly that, i.e. `vittorio` as the destination field. Not sure why you created another answer to say exactly the same thing. Having it in the source also makes no difference since we were not using it anyway.

Comment: Having it in the source doesn't make sense because in the source go the values you want to map in the new log. Write multiple fields there and the destination creates redundancy. My answer has the only purpose of making this more clear, and for me just make more sense to write in the source all the field you want to take from the old log.

Comment: And also, your answer didn't work because `request.end_point` was not accessible, that is still a mystery to me.

Comment: I've updated my answer because the correct way to access nested fields in logstash is `[request][end_point]` not `request.end_point`, dreaded copy/paste

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it drove me to a more `correct` solution, thanks!

Comment: it didn't work either... it works only if I do `"_source": ["request.end_point"]` and then `fields => { "request" => "vittorio" }`. This will result correct in the output, adding a new key `vittorio` and the nested value `end_point`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simply that you don't have to specify the "new" field using the query_template.

```
"_source": ["request"] # here you specify the field you want from the query result.
```

and then

```
filter{
  if [class] == "DPAPIINTERNAL" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "10.1.10.16"
      index => "dp_audit-2017.02.16"
      query_template => "/home/vittorio/Documents/elastic-queries/matching-requestaw.json"
      fields => {"request" => "new_key"} # here you add the fields and will tell elastich filter to put request inside new_key
    }
  }
}
```

That worked for me!